# How to translate "telephone" or "Chinese whispers"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm unable to find a name in Esperanto for this game, despite being a very common game in other languages. The phrase I'm translating uses "Stille Post" in German and "téléphone" in French, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikidata entry Q151939](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q151939) (since [this revision of 2017-12-24](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q151939&oldid=613127057)) suggests *telefonludo*, which seems sufficiently plausible, but I couldn't find any usages of that elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

### From word roots, suffixes and prefixes:

#### verb

The action being done is sharing, passing on or giving. This means that the word will contain transdoni or doni or kunhavigi. I prefer *kunhavigi*.

#### accusative noun

The things being shared are words or phrases so it will be vort- or fraz-. I prefer *fraz*.

#### adverb

The way in which it is being done is within a group or together so this part of the word could be kun- or komun- or intergrup-. I like *intergrup*.

#### What it is

It's a game. so... *ludo*.

## Result

*intergrupfrazkunhavigludo* = Game in which phrases are shared within a group